# Django で、バルクREPLACE をする方法が知りたい

Tags: python, mysql, django

Python Django の モデルマネージャを使って、MySQL のバルクREPLACE を実行する方法をご存知であれば教えてください。

```
class SpamModel(models.Model):
    ...

SpamModel.objects.bulk_create([
    SpamModel(**item) for item in items])
```

このようにバルクインサートを行っていますが、ここで INSERT ではなく REPLACE をしたいのです。

このようなイメージです。

```
SpamModel.objects.bulk_create([
    SpamModel(**item) for item in items], mysql_replace=True)
```

こんなコードでできないものかと。

```
REPLACE INTO spam_spammodel (a, b) VALUES (...), (...), (...), ...
```

このようなSQLが出ることを想定しています

※ UPSERT ではありません。また、DELETE してからの INSERT でもありません。あくまで、MySQL の REPLACE 文での実行をしたいのです。

Answer (score 1):

目的は、SpamModel.somefieldで"X"の場合、"z"に変えるなら、`.update()`が使えるかと思います：

```
SpamModel.objects.filter(somefield='x').update(somefield='z')
```

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE
>   index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.
>
> **Note:** 
>   *REPLACE makes sense only if a table has a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE
>
>   index. Otherwise, it becomes equivalent to INSERT, because there is no
>
>   index to be used to determine whether a new row duplicates another.*

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

ならば、Djangoで実現したいなら、DELETE してからの INSERT になると思います。なければ、自分で[SQL文を発行する](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)しかないでしょうか？

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly